# Browserify require dependencies

Tags: backbone.js, browserify

I am using Browserify to handle the Javascript libraries that my application need as follows:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
```

This all works fine. However, when I try and add backbone-localstorage as follows:

```
var LocalStorage = require('backbone-localstorage');
```

It says that `Backbone` is not defined (in backbone-localstorage).
It looks like jQuery is passed into Backbone like this:

```
Backbone.$ = $;
```

But

```
LocalStorage.Backbone = Backbone;
```

Does not seem to yield the same results.
What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Changed to use backbone.localstorage instead of backbone-localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

```
Backbone.LocalStorage = require("backbone.localstorage");
```

See [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backbone.localstorage#commonjs)

Comment: Interesting, I was looking at backbone-localstorage which seems to be different, I don't need that one as well though do I? backbone.localstorage just says it is an 'adaptor'. Seems to be working with just backbone.localstorage though

Comment: @timhc22 Oh they're different modules, I didn't even notice. `backbone-localstorage` seems to be fairly dead. If you compare [this](https://github.com/robmoorman/backbone-localstorage) and [this](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) the last one seems way more active. It also has way more downloads from NPM. I would stick with `backbone.localstorage` based only on those numbers if they work the same way.

Comment: yea I've been doing this tutorial http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2012/09/13/backbone-js-for-absolute-beginners-getting-started-part-2/ so probably just not been updated. it seems to be working with the other one though either way! thanks